# How to check what flags were helpful

Tags: support, flags, profile-page, flag-history

When I check my profile, I only get to see the info about flags begin helpful/declined **for posts**. It says that I've got e.g. 19 reported and 15 approved for comments but I don't get to see **which ones** I was mistaken about.

How can I see the listing for all the three categories of flags listed together? (I'm mostly interested in the declines because I'd like to avoid raising false positives.)

Comment: Are you only talking about comment flags?

Comment: There are two or three types of flags but the listing accessible by clicking the link on the profile only shows one category (or at least it doesn't list **all** the flags). So I meant **any** type there is of those that are not listed. It'd be good to know when the moderators don't agree with me on what's flagable so I can provide a better feed-back.